# When should a Kafka Streams application be split into multiple applications?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

How do you know when to split up a Kafka Streams application into multiple applications?

For example, I'm working on a containerized Streams application that processes records streamed from a database and outputs them into a new stream. Each table has its own stream -- both on the consumption and production side -- and each new stream that is produced is to be used for the same logical purpose.

In this case, would it be wise to split up the application into separate stream applications for each table stream or would it be better to perform all of that processing in the same application?

Here are what I see as the pros and cons of splitting up a Kafka Streams application into multiple applications:

**Pros**

- Changing how a particular table stream is processed in the future means only needing to restart the containers that perform that processing.
- Each application is extremely light-weight and dedicated to its one purpose (process the database table stream and output in this new way, in this example).

**Cons**

- Management of all of these additional containers becomes more difficult.
- Code sharing becomes more difficult as shared resources like serializers/deserializers now need to turn into libraries rather than imported from a different section of the application.

Comment: If you used Avro GenericRecord types for the data and a Avro schema registry, then serializers don't have to be shared.

Comment: It would depend on the volume of data you are processing. Can a single streams application keep up with 5 input/output streams? Do you anticipate the data volume to increase soon?

Comment: I believe you already mentioned the most important pros/cons. It also depends on how simple it is to set up new applications for each table. In case you have a good platform for this (e.g. Kubernetes, CloudFoundry), I would split them up. One further advantage would be independent scaling and independent deployment -- in the future different teams might be in charge of the separate applications.